# PHP: Array Convert comma separated string to int

Tags: php, arrays

I just tried to parse my array that contains numbers separated with comma into numbers without the comma, but still in array form. But it didn't work.

My code:

```
$total = $this->input->post('total');
$arrTot = array_filter(array_slice($total, 20));
print_r($arrTot);
```

Array result:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 10,000
   [1] => 100,000
   [2] => 200,000
)
```

My desired output was to erase the comma in all number:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10000
    [1] => 100000
    [2] => 200000
)
```

I've tried with something just like this but it seems not even close with my desired output:

```
$total = $this->input->post('total');
$arrTot = array_filter(array_slice($total, 20));
for ($i=0; $i < count($arrTot); $i++) { 
    $valTot=str_replace( ',', '', $arrTot[$i]);
    print_r($valTot);
}
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to process each of the values in the array:

```
$arrTot = array('10,000', '100,000', '200,000');
array_walk($arrTot, function (&$v) {
    $v = str_replace(',', '', $v);
});
print_r($arrTot);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10000
    [1] => 100000
    [2] => 200000
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ONHLJ)

Comment: Damn it! I don't even know that there is array_walk, thanks man you save ma day.

Comment: @baimWonk it's just a shorthand way of writing the loop you already had. All the other answers show how to fix your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

you might assign new value to current variable.

```
$arrTot = array_filter(array_slice($total, 20));
for ($i=0; $i < count($arrTot); $i++) { 
    $arrTot[$i]=str_replace( ',', '', $arrTot[$i]);
}
print_r($arrTot);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the desired output, you need to replace the elements in the main array without comma.

```
$total = $this->input->post('total');
$arrTot = array_filter(array_slice($total, 20));

foreach ($arrTot as $key => $aTot) {
    $arrTot[$key] = str_replace(',','',$arrTot[$i);
}
var_dump($arrTot);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
echo "<pre>";
$arr = array('10,000','100,000','200,000');
print_r($arr);
//result 
   Array
  (
      [0] => 10,000
      [1] => 100,000
      [2] => 200,000
  )
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
   $new[] = str_replace(',','',$value);
}
print_r($new);
Array
(
    [0] => 10000
    [1] => 100000
    [2] => 200000
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
$arr = ['10,000','100,000','200,000'];
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
  $arr[$key] = (int)str_replace(',','',$val);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `str_replace` to achieve desired result

```
$arrTot = array('10,000', '100,000', '200,000');

foreach($arrTot as $key => $value){
  $arrTot[$key] = str_replace(",","",$value);
}

print_r($arrTot);
```